# Search for specific text in a sheet and adding a note to that cell dependent on its content

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to add a button to a sheet so search the names of people and add a note specific the persons name. So far I have used an onEdit(e) script but this would be a list that is copy/pasted each month and not user edited. But when converting this to a script that runs with a "button" I receive a value error.

```
      function onEdit(e){ 
       var notes = {
        'rep 1': 'Only works Sundays, off Thurdays',
        'rep 2': 'Saturdays and Sundays',
        'rep 3': 'Saturdays/Chats only',
        'rep 4': 'Saturdays',
        'rep 5': 'Every third shift', }
       if(notes[e.value.toLowerCase()]) {
         return e.range.setNote(notes[e.value.toLowerCase()]);}}
```

Comment: Please provide images for currrent data and how you would like it changed.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is what you are looking for. The current script will add a note when the name is user typed. I am looking to attach a script to the "notes" button to read through the data in column A (this will essentially be copy and pasted each month) and add the notes based on the name of the person in the column. (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-GL56VXSsGf_GK3oWkhzi1jmf1XFeKBW/view?usp=sharing), https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a9fR12K-7PeKXYbqU7Kua037LKTNUMAR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
function iguessthis() {
  const notes = {'rep 1': 'Only works Sundays, off Thurdays','rep 2': 'Saturdays and Sundays','rep 3': 'Saturdays/Chats only','rep 4': 'Saturdays','rep 5': 'Every third shift'};
  let v = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
  if(notes.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setNote(notes[v]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work however it requires a cell to be selected individually. If you were to highlight a column it will only display the first note multiple times.

Comment: Before we go any further can you explain what you want a little better.  Perhaps you can take images of your sheets and show what happens before and after the script runs.  I guessed at the answer based upon your current script but I really have no idea what you really want because your explanation is incomplete.  ]

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a work around but I am unable to add images due to the reputation requirement.